# Android google maps - keytool generates SHA1 instead of MD5 hash

Tags: android

When I trying to generate MD5 key using Keytool "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"
with this parameters:

C:>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool.exe" -list -alias and
roiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\user1.android\debug.keystore" -storepass andro
id -keypass android
androiddebugkey, 20.09.2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
Huella Digital de Certificado (SHA1): ED:55:7E:68:28:7A:90:28:B1:2F:62:3A:B5:94:06:DD:C4:6C:D6:20

and when I'm trying to submit this "ED:55:7E:68:28:7A:90:28:B1:2F:62:3A:B5:94:
06:DD:C4:6C:D6:20" key to http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html - it is not working. How to make it work? Why am I having SHA1 instead of MD5 ?

Comment: solution found: I should have run this one: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\keytool.exe"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the Keytool from jdk1.6

Comment: can i get only keytool.exe for jdk1.6? will it work alone? if so where to get it?

Answer (score 15):

Add `-v` in your commmand as shown below:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore .....
```

Comment: this actually works on jdk 1.7! it shows MD5, ShA1 and SHA256.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to get your `MD5 fingerprint`.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey 
-keystore "Your debug key location" -storepass android -keypass android
```

You can also get the full tutorial at [androidcookers.co.cc](http://www.androidcookers.co.cc/2011/12/show-google-map-on-your-android-app.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey 
-keystore C:\Users\DON\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

DON is ur system name

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\itt\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not installed Java 7 myself, but there is a new command line argument to its keytool, namely -keyalg.

I know you can specify -keyalg RSA, so maybe -keyalg MD5 will give you the right key.