# google map key (SHA1) certificate

Tags: android

I am using following command to generate MD5 cetificate. But i am getting SHA1 certificate. Which is giving invalid finger print while generating certificate. Where I am doing mistake.

`keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ./.android/debug.keystore`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914187/android-google-maps-keytool-generates-sha1-instead-of-md5-hash try `keytool -v -list ....`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.
I was having same issue few days before.If you use `JDK 1.7` then it will generate `SHA1` instead of `MD5` fingerprint.To generate `MD5` fingerprint in `JDK 1.7` use (-v) option of the keytool.

for example : `keytool -v -list -keystore [your keystore path]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will show MD5 also

```
keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ./.android/debug.keystore
```

added -v between keytool and -list.